# How can I make the first character of a string to be uppercase in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Capitalizing word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417677/capitalizing-word-in-a-string)
>   [Make first letter upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-upper-case)

I have a string like this:

```
var a = "this is a string";
```

Is there a simple way I can make the first character change to uppercase?

This is a string

Comment: Your question is actually answered in another question: [Capitalizing word in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417677/capitalizing-word-in-a-string)

Comment: @Gabe, that's not a dupe since it's the first letter in each word. This question _is_ a dupe however, see Drahakar's link.

Comment: @pax: What I meant is that *the question itself* has the answer to this question. It's not as good as yours, but better than most of the answers in Drahakar's link.

Comment: @Gabe: I don't agree with closing questions because the answer is provided in a _different_ question. That just makes answers harder to find. But I'm not overly fussed in this case: I have no doubt this question will be closed, but because there's a duplicate _question._

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
    a = Char.ToUpper(a[0]) + a.Substring(1);
```

If you're sure that the string won't be null or empty, you can drop the `if` statement as well but I prefer to program defensively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about the fact that a string is immutable, than you can return a new string instance.

```
var a = "this is a string";
a = string.Format("{0}{1}", char.ToUpper(a[0]), a.Remove(0, 1));
```

But, if you are going to end up needing to do more string manipulation on the same value, you may want to consider using a StringBuilder instead.

```
var a = "this is a string";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(a);
builder.Replace(a[0], char.ToUpper(a[0]), 0, 1);
```